# Drupal 7 - Error on Checkout, e-Commerce

Tags: commerce

I installed a **e-commerece** module for my website. And enalbed all the supporting files under 'modules'. I'm able to **add products and view them** and can also **add to the shopping cart.** however when i **checkout**, it sends me some here..like this

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 
'exid' at row 1: INSERT INTO {ec_customer} (type, exid, uid, name) VALUES 
(:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, 
:db_insert_placeholder_3); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => anonymous 
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 4mePOKXg5_hhSCYgVSumyWMhsej6EZ5LRLKafRfPBTA     
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => ) in drupal_write_record() 
(line 6975 of C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\includes\common.inc).
```

Does anyone know why is it throwing an error.

Comment: Did you install Drupal commerce by yourself or are you using the commerce-kickstart distribution?

Comment: I installed the e-commerece module all by myself! Didn't used the commerece kickstart.

Comment: This is not Commerce at all, it is the e-Commerce module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Drupal commerce, try installing [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).  There are detailed [installation instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1291122) available.

Drupal Commerce is fairly complex and there are lots of different types of errors that can result.  Commerce Kickstart is a package (known in Drupal as an installation profile) that sets up most of the commerce stuff for you.  If you're not experienced in working with Drupal, this is an easy way to get started without having to troubleshoot error messages.

If you do try Commerce Kickstart, do so from a new site.  If you try to install over Drupal Commerce it could get messy.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! Will try the commerece kickstart. Are Drupal e-Commerece module and commerece kickstart different? Or is commerece kickstart is just a way to install the e-Commerece module.

Thanks again!

Comment: First, some terms clarification: the name of the e-commerce module for Drupal 7 is "Drupal Commerce."  In past versions of Drupal, there were modules like "Drupal E-commerce," so to avoid confusion please call the module "Drupal Commerce."

Comment: To answer your question, yes, Drupal Commerce and Commerce Kickstart are the same project.  Commerce Kickstart simply includes basic configuration and helps you set things up your first time.  (You can always do advanced customizations later if necessary.)

Comment: Drupal Commerce or Ubercart? what's your pick. Considering that Ubercart has more payment options than Drupal commerce, i'm little confused here.